# Seeking Open Source ISO Metadata Editor?

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, metadata, iso-19115

I am looking for a free open source ISO metadata editor for the development of an enterprise database.

It will mostly be used for documenting shapefiles and GeoTIFFs.

Hoping that it will be an intuitive software since a range of skill levels will be working with it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a metadata management tool for QGIS called "**Metatools**". I haven't tried it yet but it offers ISO style metadata handling:

[image]

Comment: This plugin no longer exists

Answer (score 8):

Check out [CatMDEdit](http://catmdedit.sourceforge.net/). It's open-source and I think its pretty useful for editing metadata related to spatial data. From their website:

> CatMDEdit is a metadata editor tool that facilitates the documentation
>   of resources, with special focus on the description of geographic
>   information resources.

It's also ISO compliant:

> Metadata edition in conformance with "ISO 19115. Geographic
>   Information - Metadata" standard (ISO 19115:2003/Cor 1 2006, ISO/TS
>   19139:2007 XML encoding). Edition interfaces adapted to different
>   metadata profiles:
>
> ISO 19115 comprehensive metadata model.
>
> ISO 19115 Core metadata for geographic datasets.

Comment: Unmaintained as of May 2022

Answer (score 3):

- You probably already heard about [GeoNetwork](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/) which is an [osgeo](http://www.osgeo.org/) project supporting metadata standards. You will find all information on the link above and an online example [here](http://www.geocat.ch/geonetwork/srv/eng/geocat).
- [MD Web](http://www.mdweb-project.org/index.php?lang=en) is an open source for cataloging spatial information. It is ISO 19115 and ISO 19139 compliant. It is developed by a french research institute and available in French, English, Italian, Spanish, and Portuguese. See the [editor page](http://www.geomatys.com/en/mdweb) for more details.

If you just need to enter metadata information, I would also recommend using the Metatools QGIS plugin, but if you want to deploy a database, Geonetwork or MD-Web are probably more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [GeoNode](http://geonode.org/). My colleagues and I have been using it for a while to set up a Spatial Data Infrastructure. It bundles PostGIS, GeoServer and GeoExplorer, to create a sort of a Content Management System for geospatial data. It's pretty interesting that I can just drag a shapefile to the browser and GeoNode will upload it to PostGis, register it on GeoServer and give me a form to fill in the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the **[ISO 19115-compliant editor 'metabeta'](http://servizi.regione.toscana.it/sgr-iso19115)** developed by Regione Toscana (an italian local government).

DISCLAIMER: I am one of the developers for this product.

Answer (score 1):

Beside GeoNetwork, as proposed by @simo, you may be interested by [EUOSME](http://www.osor.eu/projects/euosme). For more information, see [there](http://www.inspire-geoportal.eu/EUOSME_GEOPORTAL/userguide/about.html). See also this [online example](http://www.inspire-geoportal.eu/index.cfm/pageid/342).