# Seeking open source Metadata management tool

Tags: software-recommendations, metadata, data-management, web

I am looking for an open source web based metadata management tool for geographic data. I have gone through [Seeking Open Source ISO Metadata Editor?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16245/seeking-open-source-iso-metadata-editor/16247#16247)
It recommends a tool like Geonetwork. Geonetwork at first looked promising but has several issues while installing (tried on windows). I am unable to install it despite asking for help on several forums.

I have gone through this link listing quite a few tools : https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Metadata_software

Do you have experience with any of it?